# How to register service worker for Firebase Cloud Messaging in Play framework?

Tags: scala, firebase, playframework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement FCM (firebase cloud messaging) using play framework.

This is my serviceWorker:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log('Received a push message', event);
    var jsonObj = event.data.json();
    var title= jsonObj.notification.title;
    var bodyn= jsonObj.notification.body;
    var icons= jsonObj.notification.icon;
    console.log('Received a push message', title);
    var notificationOptions = {
     body: bodyn,
     icon: icons,
     tag: title,
     data: null
    };
    if (self.registration.showNotification) {
       self.registration.showNotification(title, notificationOptions);
       return;
     } else {
        new Notification(title, notificationOptions);
    }
});
```

In the main.scala.html file I wrote this code:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/firebase/firebase-app.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/firebase/firebase-messaging.js")"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/firebase/firebase.js")"></script>

            <script>
            var config = {....};
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
            const messaging = firebase.messaging();
           messaging.usePublicVapidKey("...........");

            messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(function () {
            console.log('Notification permission granted.');
            messaging.getToken()
            .then(function (refreshedToken){
                console.log('Token refreshed.');
                sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);                   
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token',err);
            });

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
        });
        messaging.onMessage(function (data) {
            console.log("ok");
            const notificationTitle = data.notification.title;
            const notificationOptions = {
                body: data.notification.body,
                icon: data.notification.icon,
            };
        });
```

The problem that I got from the browser is :

> "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP res…code (404) was received when fetching the script.

the service worker is mentioned in the main file which execute the first one in my project.

Comment: That's JS, not specific to Play

Comment: so why is always returning the same error?

Comment: The JS code being on the client/browser side, not calling in anyway Play, the error cannot in anyway be caused by Play.